# How to make my simple Datagrid to have default frontend style?

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, orocrm, orocommerce

This is how my current datagrid shows as:

[image: current datagrid]

I have tried to extend the core `frontend-product-search-grid` but it appears styleless as well

my datagrids.yml

```
datagrids:
    razoyo-productbybrand-grid:
        # extends: frontend-product-search-grid
        options:
            frontend: true
            entityHint: oro.product.entity_plural_label
            entity_pagination: true
            requireJSModules:
                - oroproduct/js/app/datagrid/frontend-product-display-options-builder
                - oroproduct/js/app/datagrid/frontend-product-filters-events-dispatcher-builder
        extended_entity_name: '%oro_product.entity.product.class%'    
        source:
            type: orm 
            query:
                select:
                    - product.id
                   # - product.sku
                   # - product.brand as 
                    - product.denormalizedDefaultName as productName
                   # - product.pagetemplate_id
                   # - product.category_id
                from:
                    - { table: '%oro_product.entity.product.class%', alias: product }
                where:
                    and:
                    - product.brand = :brandId
            bind_parameters:
                # Get the "brandId" parameter from the datagrid
                # and set its value to the "brandId" parameter in the datasource query
                brandId: brandId            

        columns:
            productName:
                label: oro.product.names.label
        properties:
            id: ~
            view_link:
                type:  url 
                route: oro_product_frontend_product_view
                params: [ id ]
            newArrival: ~
            unit: ~
```

my productsbybrand.yml

```
layout:
    actions:
        - '@setBlockTheme':
            themes: 'productsbybrand.html.twig'
        - '@add':
            id: product_by_brand_block
            parentId: page_content
            blockType: block
```

my productsbybrand.html.twig

```
{% block _product_by_brand_block_widget %}
    {% import 'OroDataGridBundle::macros.html.twig' as dataGrid %}
    {% include 'OroDataGridBundle:js:toolbar.html.twig' %}

    <div  class="js-frontend-datagrid-grid-views-tpl"></div>

    {% block content %}
         {# Accessing route id from request and passing that in as brandId #}    
         {{ dataGrid.renderGrid('razoyo-productbybrand-grid', {brandId: app.request.get('id')}) }}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

This is how I desire it to show:
[image: desired datagrid]

Comment: what happens when you try to render `frontend-product-search-grid` directly?

to me it seems the datagrid is rendered correctly since it's containing single column without any sorters or filters

Comment: Two reasons:
1. I can simply extend the `frontend-product-search-grid` but it also shows like a basic ugly looking datagrid, with more columns. It does not have the same design as it does for the `/product` route. 
2. And also, the reason I did not simply extend that is because, I needed to put a `where` condition to render only products by `brandId` and `frontend-product-search-grid` uses a search index doc `oro_product_WEBSITE_ID` which does not have a `brand_id` field that I need for the `where` condition.

Comment: and what about setting more layout options as oro originaly does?

https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/views/layouts/blank/oro_product_frontend_product_search/product_search.yml

Comment: I guess, I will have to try that route. I wish there were more documentation explaining that. Thanks! :)

Comment: me personally would try to render `frontend-product-search-grid` directly (not yours, but theirs) and see how it looks, it can help to determine if problem is somewhere in Twig or that area, or in datagrid definition itself